# Is it ever correct to use “end” after the name of a month?

Tags: grammar, dialects, time, syntactic-analysis

I’ve heard some people say things like *September end* or *June end* when I’m used to hearing the *end of September* or the *end of June*.

Is the former usage (meaning, the “something end” collocation) correct or standard somewhere?

Comment: That sounds like a foreign use, like the way some people say *Friday week* to mean next Friday.

Comment: Can you get that to me by August end? Business-speak if I'm not mistaken. Similarly, "It will be finished by week's end."

Comment: There's nothing wrong with "Friday week". Perhaps the English are foreign! But we wouldn't say "September end"; it's more likely to be "end September".

Comment: It might be a contraction/mis-hearing of *September's end*, although that sounds quite archaic to my (UK) ear. Alternatively it might be an attempt at being more specific than the more generic 'month end', which is definitely more a business expression.

Comment: @tchrist, ‘next Friday’ and ‘Friday week’ do not mean the same thing in all dialects. If today is Monday the 4th, some dialects will take ‘next Friday’ to refer to the first-coming Friday, i.e., Friday the 8th, but ‘Friday week’ to refer to the Friday that belongs to the following week, i.e., Friday the 15th. On Saturday the 9th, of course, both would refer to the same day. [I’m not actually sure if there are dialects where both forms are used, but ‘next Friday’ also means ‘Friday of next week’; if not, the ‘some dialects’ restriction above does not apply]

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet; beware 'of course'. To me, *Friday week* means the same as *a week on Friday*, i.e. Friday the 22nd if said on Saturday 9th.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is Indian English.

> VAL refinery to reopen by June-end

from [The Times of India](http://articles.timesofindia.indiatimes.com/2013-06-08/bhubaneswar/39833195_1_refinery-lanjigarh-private-miners)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are asking the difference between 'the end of September' and 'September end'.
They are both correct but the first one I mentioned is more common.

Comment: That wasn’t actually what he was asking, no.

Answer (score 0):

This can be used to create a more poetic feel, as in 'the flowers that are blooming at June end'.

Comment: Where in the world is that wording used?

Comment: Try googling it. As I said above, it is used to create a more poetic feel. You would see it in poetry and lyrics, art titles and theatre. Try this, if you must need help:https://soundcloud.com/jesh-das-kleine-katzen/mays-end. Here is another:http://www.youtube.com/user/MandyDecembersEnd.

Comment: So it's not in everyday speech.

Comment: @Tristan - That depends on who you are talking to...